# Postgres: How to setup an index on timestamptz using a time interval?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-indexes

I have a query that I need to optimize using indexes. Is there any way I can index the column assigned_at which is a timestamptz type. I was thinking of using a GIST index initally of assigned_at, is there any way I can incorporate that given I will have to use now() or pass in the current date time which is mutable and cant be indexed.

```
select id from foo f where 
f.context_id = $1 
and (f.assigned_at <= (now() - interval '60 second') or f.assigned_at is null)
```

Open for suggestions to setup an index for this query! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No I haven't! Will try this but if i do the above how can i make an index on the timestamp bit using an index ?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? this both scenarios use the index: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e638e32af8b046a4ef807e09832db8c6

Comment: Your query has unbalanced parentheses.  I can probably guess what you meant, but it would be nice if we didn't have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the query you posted, a composite index using  `context_id` and `assigned_at` should do the trick:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_foo ON foo (context_id,assigned_at);
```

Depending on your data, the `OR` conditional might slow down your query a bit. An alternative is to split this conditional into two different queries:

```
SELECT * FROM foo f 
WHERE f.context_id = 1 AND f.assigned_at <= (now() - interval '60 second')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM foo f WHERE f.context_id = 1 AND f.assigned_at IS NULL;
```

As always, play with both queries and test which approach fits your data best.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=90478e12308b5f3dd26c1afa40477284)

Answer (score 1):

A simple btree index on `(context_id, assigned_at)` is usable for that query.  But to fully use all parts, it would need to read the index twice and do a BitmapOr between them.  Depending on how selective it thinks each term will be, it might choose to take a different approach, for example using the index only for context_id and applying the time part as a filter.

```
explain analyze select id from foo f where 
f.context_id = 7 
and (f.assigned_at <= (now() - interval '60 second') or f.assigned_at is null);
                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on foo f  (cost=8.88..12.90 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.031..0.041 rows=7 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (((context_id = 7) AND (assigned_at <= (now() - '00:01:00'::interval))) OR ((context_id = 7) AND (assigned_at IS NULL)))
   Filter: ((assigned_at <= (now() - '00:01:00'::interval)) OR (assigned_at IS NULL))
   Heap Blocks: exact=4
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=8.88..8.88 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.024..0.025 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_context_id_assigned_at_idx  (cost=0.00..4.44 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((context_id = 7) AND (assigned_at <= (now() - '00:01:00'::interval)))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_context_id_assigned_at_idx  (cost=0.00..4.43 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=7 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((context_id = 7) AND (assigned_at IS NULL))
```